# How to save original height of a series of boxes when height is unkown?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of boxes:

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

The css:

```
.box {
   height: auto;
}
```

The actual height is set only once the boxes are loaded with content, therefore I don't know their height at start.

```
$(".box").each(function(){
    boxHeight = $(this).height();
});
```

Bu that's wrong, basically I need to save those heights and be able to reuse them later on

Comment: `height()` is a method, not a property. You need to do `$(this).css('height', boxHeight)`. What you are trying to accomplish is unclear. What is boxHeight? At what point do you know what boxHeight is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to save the heights for later then use jQuery's data object to store the value.

Updated my answer based on Jasper's feedback and added a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/5LvJT/

```
$('.box').each(function() {
    $.data(this, 'height', $(this).height());
});

$('.box').click(function() {
   var height = $.data(this, 'height');
});​
```

You can then access the height for each one later on via

```
$.data(whatever box, 'height');
```

Comment: Better yet you can use the `$.data()` method which is quite a bit faster: `$.data(this, 'height', $(this).height());`

Comment: Here's a JSPerf showing the performance difference between the different uses of jQuery data functions: http://jsperf.com/jquery-data-vs-jqueryselection-data/22

Comment: @Jasper - thanks for the perf info Jasper. Great thing to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

This will store each height in an array:

```
var heights = $('.box').map(function(index, box) { return $(box).height(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$(".box").each(function() {
    var t = $(this);
    t.data("originalHeight",t.height());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.box').each( function() {
    $(this).data('height', $(this).height());
});

$(".box").height( $(".box").data('height') );
```